# "Race" appearance. How to create a consistent line length

Tags: java

I have created the following but need the output line to maintain a consistent width to give the appearance of a race. I also need to ensure that the racers do not slip back past the start.

Currently, the output plots correctly, but the line only extends to the racers position.

Also, when there is a "slip" it appears that the racer sometimes moves back to start. I'm not sure if that is solved with a consistent length of "race track" as well.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Race {    
public static void main(String []args) {

int finish=70,tort=1,hare=1,rtime=0;
System.out.println("ON YOUR MARK, GET SET\nBANG !!!!!\nAND THEY'RE OFF !!!!!\n");

do{
    hare=movehare(hare);
    tort=movetort(tort);
    print(tort,hare);
    rtime++;
}
while(tort<finish&&hare<finish);

    if(tort>hare ){
    System.out.println("\nTORTOISE WINS!\n");
    }

    else if(tort<hare ){
    System.out.println("\nHARE WINS!\n");
    }

    else{
    System.out.println("IT\'S A TIE!\n");
    }    
}

public static void print(int t,int h){

  int i;

    if(h==t){

        for(i=0;i<h;i++)
        System.out.print("_");
        System.out.println("OUCH!!!");
    }  

    else if(h<t){      

        for(i=0;i<h;i++)
        System.out.print("_");
        System.out.print("H");

        for(i=0;i<(t-h);i++)
        System.out.print("_");
        System.out.print("T");            
    }

    else{

      for(i=0;i<t;i++)
      System.out.print("_");
      System.out.print("T");

      for(i=0;i<(h-t);i++)
      System.out.print("_");
      System.out.print("H");
    }

    System.out.println();
}

public static int movehare(int r ){

int num;
num=(int)(Math.random()*10);

if(num<2){
 r-=2;
}
else if(num<5){
  r++;
}
else if(num<6){
  r-=12;
}
else if(num<8){
  r+=9;
}

if(r< 1 ){
  r=1;
}
  return r;
}

public static int movetort(int t){

int num;
num=(int)(Math.random()*10);

if(num<5){
t+=3;
}

else if(num<7){
t-= 6;
}

else{
t++;
}

if(t<1){
t=1;
}

return t;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print extra "_" after each of the IF branches in your print method

```
    if(h != t){
        for(i = Math.max(h,t); i < 70; i++){
            System.out.print("_");
        }
    }
```

Note: The line breaks will be off when the H == T because you print "Ouch!!!", so you'll have to check for that and accommodate.

Comment: Thank you! I added the code and the track is now a consistent length. Now I just have to figure out how to prevent the racers from slipping so far back that is doesn't look like a race.

Comment: It's possible you could track how many turns have passed and make it so they never split further back than that (or some kind of combination) so in the unfortunate event that they repeated get the same number and get pushed back -12 it wouldn't affect them multiple times.